# Wha'ts wrong with this PHP If statement that uses the 'is greater than' operator?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, bbpress

In this case I want to make the code work only if there are more than 5 replies.

```
<?php if ( bbp_topic_reply_count() > 5 ) : ?>
    <?php query_posts('gdsr_sort=thumbs&post_type=bbp_reply&posts_per_page=2&post_parent='.$post->ID); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php  the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'type' => 'avatar' ) ); ?>
        <?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'type' => 'name' ) ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The replies are effectively being shown in the code below:

```
<h4><?php bbp_topic_reply_count(); ?></h4>
```

But it seems like its not working in the if statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the return value of `bbp_topic_reply_count()`? Is it a number, or is it some HTML code which contains the number somewhere inside with formatting etc. If it is someting like `<div class="blah">5</div>` then it obviously won't get you the number 5 in an `if` statement. - Espacially so if it **prints out** the result instead of `return`ing it.

Comment: But you accepted Matt's answer which says exactly the oppsoite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```
if ( bbp_get_topic_reply_count() > 5)
```

As with many templatey functions in various PHP libraries, there are two variants of this function. One, `bbp_topic_reply_count()`, automatically echoes the count, rather than returning it. The other, `bbp_get_topic_reply_count()` actually returns the value to you rather than echoing it.

Comment: Thanks! Are you familiar with bbPress or this is a standard way of making PHP functions?

Comment: @alexchenco I'm not familiar with bbPress, but this kind of behaviour and naming is very common in template libraries; I think I first came across it in both WordPress and ZenPhoto. It saves you having to `echo` things all over the place, while still letting you get hold of the values that the templates are echoing if you need to. So I just guessed the name that the "get" function would have and Googled it to make sure it existed before I answered :)

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest using

```
if (bbp_get_topic_reply_count() > 5):
```

The reason for this is that the function `bbp_topic_reply_count()` does not return the count value, instead it outputs this value. So when you compare the return value of bbp_topic_reply_count it is null and this produces the following statement

```
if (0 > 5) :
```

Which of course is always false.

Comment: np, I found out here http://phpdoc.ftwr.co.uk/bbpress-plugin/bbPress/TemplateTags/_bbp-includes---bbp-topic-template.php.html#functionbbp_get_topic_reply_count

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the coding conventions of WordPress but I'm sure you don't have to open and close the php tag `<?php` in **every line**.

Answer (score 0):

`bbp_topic_reply_count()` isn't returning the reply count. It is only echoing it. This means you can't use it as a comparison because the function doesn't return a number to compare against.  I am not familiar with the bbpress functions, but you will have to find an alternative.